# serviceless authentication with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I try my best as a newbie to make a very simple authentication page in my app.

here is my MainActivity class :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)  // I replaced activity_main by activity_auth who is made for the sign in and sign up page with a bottom-menu-bar navigation
    var logUser = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username)  //username
    var logPwd = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password)   //password
    /*
    var btnGo = findViewById<Button>(R.id.BtnLogin)      // btn submit
    var btnHelp = findViewById<Button>(R.id.BtnHelp)     // btn pwd lost

    btnGo.setOnClickListener {
        val userName = logUser.text;
        val passWord = logPwd.text;
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "WELCOME $userName", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        // the code to validate the user_name and password combination will be here
        // if logUser + logPwd are good the user should be redirect to "activity_main"

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)*/

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.navigation_profil, R.id.navigation_home))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    //}
}
```

like that the application correctly displays my login page, but if I remove the comment tags and try to act on the buttons or IDs the application crashes. Are there any mistakes or things that seem strange to you?

here is my sign in layout if you need it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#444444"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/pureGold"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:text="@string/login"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:hint="@string/logUser"
        android:textColor="@color/pureWhite"
        android:textColorHint="#52afaa"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:hint="@string/logPWD"
        android:textColor="@color/pureWhite"
        android:textColorHint="#52afaa"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="289dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnLogin"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/pureBlack"
            android:text="@string/logButton1"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnHelp"
            android:layout_width="147dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/pureBlack"
            android:text="@string/logButton2"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Here is the crash logs :

```
2021-03-10 20:53:33.792 8439-8439/com.example.movie_catcher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.movie_catcher, PID: 8439
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.movie_catcher/com.example.movie_catcher.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.movie_catcher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
```

Comment: Can you add crash log?

Comment: @KishanMaurya I just edited my post with logs. thanks

Comment: The above layout that you have posted is for activity_auth. Can you also add activity_main layout?

Comment: I don't think this part of the code has any influence on the current issue. This part being isolated from the authentication.

Comment: the crash logs seem to target the buttons. I don't really understand why ...

Answer (score 0):

If found a solution, but outside MainActivity in a specific fragment :

```
val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auth_sign_in, container, false)
    (v.BtnLogin as Button).setOnClickListener {
        var SigninUser = v.username.text
        var SigninPwd = v.password.text

        if (SigninUser.toString() == "Paul") {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome $SigninUser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            startActivity(Intent(activity, MainActivity::class.java))
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unknown user : $SigninUser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```